# diretiva para colocar campos input em maiúsculo com angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Criei a seguinte diretiva, para quando um usuário digitar no input ser convertido para maiúsculo, porém, quando preciso editar esse campo para inserir uma palavra no meio do que já tinha digitado ele joga o cursor do mouse no final da palavra do input.

Ex:  Teste0 Teste2
Quando vou inserir uma outra palavra Teste0 Teste1 Teste2 ele joga o curso para o final de Teste2 ficando Teste0 Teste2Teste1.

```
return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
               if(inputValue === undefined) inputValue = '';
               var capitalized = inputValue.toUpperCase();
               if(capitalized !== inputValue) {
                   modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
                   modelCtrl.$render();
                }         
                return capitalized;
             };
             modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
             capitalize(scope[attrs.ngModel]);  // capitalize initial value
        }
       };
```

Answer (score 1):

Se o único objetivo da diretiva é transformar o texto em uppercase, você pode usar um css:

```
.uppercase { 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}
```

CSS é mais leve que o AngularJs e o resultado será o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

**@Felipe j.lemos**,

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="meuApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" capitalizado/>         
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('componente', [])
   .directive('capitalizado', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',        
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            element.css("text-transform","capitalize");
        }
    };
});

angular.module('meuApp', ['componente']);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/Ltwqs8w7/3/)

Comment: Funcionou, mas eu tive que colocar isso: element.css("text-transform","uppercase");

Comment: `Capitalize` deixa apenas a primeira letra maiúscula.